# nokia qt sdk problem

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

hi i want to make an application for nokia in nokia qt sdk.
i select mobile application when i create new project but when i run the project it built the exe file of my project i want a sis file so i can check it on my nokia device.

please give me the suggesion how i develop my project for nokia mobile in nokia qt sdk

Comment: Do you use the S^3 SDK? A good tool set for QT/Symbian development is S^3 + Cardbide + Qt for Symbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help ?

http://www.forum.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/Getting_started/Step_3.xhtml